# How to Forward GraphQL Multipart Request with GraphQL Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql, express-graphql

All of my React client requests get routed to a Node/express server for server-side rendering and then onto a Python/Django app via the graphqlExpress function from [apollo-server-express](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-express). The client uses [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client) for file uploads. Unfortunately, apollo-server-express doesn't support [multipart file requests](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec#client) and the alternative [apollo-upload-server](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-server) library automatically parses multipart requests, which would resolve before reaching Django. So, in a nutshell: Does anyone know how to forward multipart requests (i.e. streams) through Node and onto Django?

Comment: you said the problem with `apollo-upload-server` is that it resolves before reaching Django, but if you don't need it to resolve, whats the problem with `apollo-server-express` not supporting it ? wouldn't that mean that it does not resolve? (as you seem to want)

Comment: Good question. I initially thought apollo-server-express would simply pass the socket through. But, it seems to remove the socket/promise altogether. So, the request body to Django is empty.